# Can I subclass a class with generics without defining the generic?

Tags: swift

So far I've been able to subclass A, only defining the generic type as String, or any other type:

```
protocol Protocol {}

extension String : Protocol {}

class A<T:Protocol> {}

class B : A<String> {}
```

Do I have to specify the generic type or can I just inherit it without specifying it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make your `B` class also generic, you should constrain `B` for protocol which is or iherits from `Protocol` and then use this generic parameter for constraining `A`

```
class B<T: Protocol>: A<T> {}
```

```
protocol P: Protocol {}
class B<T:P>: A<T> {}
```